# Determine if flag value is valid

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitflags

I have a Number value I'm sending to an API and I want to soft check on the front end if the value is a valid "flag" before shipping it off.

So far as I can figure, a flag is any number where the bit value starts with a `1` and then is followed by zero or more `0`s, or just `0`.

In C#, this is the enum I'm sending values for:

```
[Flags]
public enum CarColors : ushort
{
    Other  = 0,
    Blue   = 1,
    Red    = 1 << 1,
    Black  = 1 << 2,
    Green  = 1 << 3,
    Orange = 1 << 4,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently doing this by converting the Number to a string of base 2, then just checking that any character after the first isn't a `1`.

```
value.toString(2).indexOf('1', 1) === -1
```